# ROW_NUMBER with partition by returns result with duplicate rows

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number, partition-by

When I run this query I get more rows than from a similar query without the `ROW_NUMBER ()` line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, value,  
    ROW_NUMBER ()  OVER (PARTITION BY  (id)
                         ORDER BY  value  DESC NULLS LAST ) max  
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE id like '%1260' ORDER BY id ASC
```

VS

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, value
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE id like '%1260' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it this way: if you have two rows with the same id and value, the second query gives you one row with the distinct id, value pair. The first gives you two rows, one with row_number() of 1 and the other with row_number() of 2.

For the following data:

```
ID   VALUE
--   -----
1    XXX
1    XXX
```

Query 1 would return

```
ID  VALUE   MAX
--  -----   ---
1   XXX      1
1   XXX      2
```

Query 2 would return

```
ID  VALUE
--  -----
1   XXX
```

Comment: I thought that first distinct is evaluated and only after that row_number()

Comment: Distinct is on the whole row. Row_number() is part of the result set, so it is subject to the distinct as well.

Answer (score 5):

The rows are no longer the same because you added a row number, so `DISTINCT` doesn't do anything. One way to avoid this is to add your row number *after* you've used `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT id, value, ROW_NUMBER ()   over (partition by  (id)   ORDER BY  value  desc NULLS LAST  ) max
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, value
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE id like '%1260'
) AS subquery
ORDER BY id ASC
```

(I'm not sure if the syntax is right for Oracle, it may need minor tweaking.)

Comment: This will will cause a query to get all rows and only then execute ROW_NUMBER(). This will cost a lot time if inner query is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 11g R2, try this.

```
WITH DistinctRow 
AS
(
     SELECT DISTINCT id, value
     FROM TABLE1 
     WHERE id like '%1260'
)
SELECT id, value,  
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by (id) ORDER BY value desc NULLS LAST) max  
FROM DistinctRow 
ORDER BY max ASC
```